# How to 8.3 name mangle like windows

Tags: samba, fuse

**Objective:** I am looking for a way to create a windows share on Ubuntu which supports *windows style* 8.3 name mangling.

```
AllYourDrivesAreBelongToUs.txt -> ALLYOU~1.TXT
```

**Rational:** The company I work for has an access based quoting software which apparently uses 8.3 name mangling under the hood to access its files.  I would like to host these files on the server it will currently not work on a non-windows based share.

I have read about [Samba's version of name mangling](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch05_04.html), but this is not the same would not match the apparent hard coded 8.3 names mangled inside the quoting software.

If I map a windows shared drive in windows, I can access a long file by truncating it to 6 characters and adding a ~1 followed by the extension as shown above.  This currently does not work with a similarly mapped samba drive in windows.

**Question:** Does anyone know of samba settings which would enable *windows style* 8.3 file mangling to make this happen or perhaps know of a filesystem wrapper which could introduce this aliasing functionality on the OS level?

Answer (score 0):

[From O'Reilly on samba](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch05_04.html):

```
[global]
    include = /usr/local/samba/lib/smb.conf.%m
```

> This resolves to `smb.conf.WfWg`  when a Window for Workgroups client attaches. Now you can create a file `/usr/local/samba/lib/smb.conf.WfWg` which might contain these options:

```
[global]
    case sensitive = no
    default case = upper
    preserve case = no
    short preserve case = no
    mangle case = yes
    mangled names= yes
```

and it has a remark:

> If you are not using Windows for Workgroups 3.1, then you probably do not need to change any of these options from their defaults.

And another note: according to the [old manual](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html)

> Samba still has to remain backward-compatible with network clients that store files in just the 8.3 format, such as Windows for Workgroups. If a user creates a file on a share called antidisestablishmentarianism.txt, a Windows for Workgroups client cannot tell it apart from another file in the same directory called antidisease.txt. Like Windows 95/98/Me and Windows NT/2000/XP, Samba has to employ a special method for translating a long filename to an 8.3 filename in such a way that similar filenames will not cause collisions. This is called name mangling, and Samba deals with this in a manner that is similar, but not identical to, Windows 95 and its successors

So there is NO 100% support for this.

Comment: I had found and read this, but as according to the quoted text "Samba deals with this in a manner that is similar, but not identical to, Windows 95 and its successors".  Samba  appends a number based on the hash of the replaced text which is unlikely to always resolve to ~1.  However it is true I haven't actually tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `shortname` option for the `mount` command:

```
shortname=mode
      Defines  the  behavior  for  creation  and  display of filenames which fit into 8.3
      characters.  If a long name for a file exists, it will always be the preferred  one
      for display.  There are four modes:

      lower  Force  the short name to lower case upon display; store a long name when the
             short name is not all upper case.

      win95  Force the short name to upper case upon display; store a long name when  the
             short name is not all upper case.

      winnt  Display  the  short name as is; store a long name when the short name is not
             all lower case or all upper case.

      mixed  Display the short name as is; store a long name when the short name  is  not
             all upper case.  This mode is the default since Linux 2.6.32.
```

Reference: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man8/mount.8.html

Comment: This seams to only apply to files which fit into 8.3 characters already instead of aliasing longer filenames with an 8.3 characters name.

Comment: This is also a mount option specifically for vfat.

Comment: Couldn't you create a FAT partition to store the files, mount the partition using `shortname=winnt`, then share the mount point via samba?

Comment: The help only mentions this defining how filenames which are already short are displayed.  I am looking for a way that allows long filenames to be accessible by a short alias.